# InputMismatchException using Scanner#nextDouble with valid values

Tags: java

Я новичок в джаве и вот мой код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class lab {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите a и b");
int a = in.nextInt();
double b = in.nextDouble();
double s;
s = ((Math.pow((b-a),3)-Math.pow(a,3))/(Math.pow(b,3)-3*a*b*b-3*a*a*b));
System.out.println("Ответы " + s);
}
}
```

при вводе значений 0.001, 0.02 и так далее я получаю :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at lab.main(lab.java:10)
```

как мне это исправить ?

Comment: `a` точно должно быть int (и использование nextInt)?

Comment: а ты подумай почему выкидывает ексепшн

Answer (score 0):

Эти две строки:

```
int a = in.nextInt();
double b = in.nextDouble();
```

подразумевают, что вы будете вводить сначала целое число, а затем число с плавающей точкой.

Если вам нужно ввести 0.001 и 0.02, то `int a = in.nextInt();` нужно заменить на `double a = in.nextDouble();`

Но даже если вы сделаете эту замену, то при вводе `0.001` у вас все равно будет генерироваться исключение. При вводе разделитель дробной части должен соответствовать настройкам языковых стандартов на вашем компьютере. Нужно вводить не `0.001`, а `0,001`